# Angular10 DevOps Extension RestApi

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I found this very helpful [github project](https://github.com/DrMueller/Angular-AzureDevOps-Poc) which is a proof of concept to make angular work in an extension of Azure DevOps. Everything works fine until i want to use the build in rest api's like "VSS/Service" or "TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient".
I found out that when i add to the includes from the tsconfig.app.json my visual studio codium ide recognizes the types in my component with `import { VssService } from 'VSS/Service';` but when i try to build the file with `ng build` the following error comes up:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'VSS/Service'
```

I tried to add to `angular.json` `scripts[]` the `VSS.SDK.min.js` file which didn't change anything.

I see that over the `init-vss-angular.js` VSS gets initialized but i have no idea how to get the rest service to use in my angular app

regads

Comment: Another way is that i make a new middleware on another server which serves me the data for my extension. Seems weird but also seems to work as needed

Comment: In my opinion this is a workaround and not an answer to my question. Why is there the library provided by npm for typscript if I'm not able to use it then? I think it's just the little knowledge i have to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the guy from the helpful [github](https://github.com/DrMueller/Angular-AzureDevOps-Poc) wrote back to me and said he has another [project](https://github.com/DrMueller/TimeLiner) which uses the REST services.
**Following is a simple solution to use DevOps RestServices within an DevOps extension with angular and typescript.**

vss-extension.json in the "files" section add:

```
{
  "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib",
  "addressable": true,
  "packagePath": "lib"
},
```

Include in the header of your extension.html file:

```
  <script src="init-vss-angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    initialize();
  </script>
```

init-vss-angular.js:

```
function initialize(explicitNotifyLoaded, usePlatformStyles, usePlatformScripts, afterSdkReadyCallback) {
    appendScript('../lib/VSS.SDK.min.js').onload = function () {
        VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: explicitNotifyLoaded || false,
            usePlatformStyles: usePlatformStyles || false,
            usePlatformScripts: usePlatformScripts || false
        });
    };

    function appendScript(scriptSource) {
        let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.src = scriptSource;
        document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
        return scriptTag;
    }
};
```

In my case I wanted to retrieve all the Repositories from the RestService and there is the magic that answers my question.

http-client-factory.service.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts" />.
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/VSS.SDK.d.ts" />.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GitHttpClient } from 'TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientFactoryService {
  public retrieveGitHTTPClient(): Promise<GitHttpClient> {
    return new Promise((resolve: any, _: any) => {
      VSS.require(['TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient'], (wit: any) => {
        const client = <GitHttpClient>wit.getClient();
        return resolve(client);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and to get the repositories in the end with http-repository.service.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts" />.
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/VSS.SDK.d.ts" />.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientFactoryService } from './http-client-factory.service';
import { GitRepository } from 'TFS/VersionControl/Contracts';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpRepositoryService {
  public constructor(
    private httpClientFactory: HttpClientFactoryService) {
  }

  public async loadRepositories(): Promise<GitRepository[]> {
    const client = await this.httpClientFactory.retrieveGitHTTPClient();
    return client.getRepositories();
  }
}
```

Give thanks to [DrMueller](https://github.com/DrMueller) for the original code.

Comment: this code only works directly on ADS right? But how you are able to run and debug it locally?

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but my guess is that your import is not required.
The author is using the `DevopsProxyService` coming from `core-services/devops-proxy/services`. Have a look to the `app.component.ts` file, he's using Angular DI to provide the `DevopsProxyService`.

`ng build` is working fine on my side :)

[image: It works!]